# Django extended user model doesn't have extended attributes

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am extending the default User model in this way

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(User):
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    company = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I am registering the user with the following view.

```
class ProfileFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'register.html'

    # Display empty form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # Process user data and add to DB.
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit = False)

            # clean form data.
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            user.company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            # returns User object if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username= username, password = password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)

                    return render(request, 'profile.html', {})

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

as you can see I redirect to profile.html once Submit is pressed on the registration page the view function I call in the form's action is as follows

```
def home(request):
    all_users = Profile.objects.all()
    city = request.user.city # this line throws error
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'city': city,'login_user': request.user, 'all_users': all_users})

Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'city'
```

but I am not able to access the city of the User error is thrown in the line marked above. What am I doing wrong. Thank You

Comment: I am not completely sure about this, but your model doesn't look right. You should have used AbstractUser instead of User. Please read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: in UserForm, model should be Profile

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access to the `User.city` attribute, when you should be doing it through `User.profile.city`.

```
city = request.user.city # this line throws error
```

Replace with:

```
# Check if the user has a profile
if hasattr(request.user, 'profile'):
    city = request.user.profile.city
# Otherwise, city is None (Or throw an Exception)
else:
    city = None
```

**Edit**

As @itzmeontv said, also replace:

```
# clean form data.
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
user.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
user.company = form.cleaned_data['company']
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

with:

```
# Clean user form data.
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
user.set_password(password)
user.save() 

# Update or create the user's profile
profile, _ = Profile.objects.get_or_create(id=user.pk)
profile.__dict__.update(user.__dict__)
profile.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
profile.company = form.cleaned_data['company']
profile.save()
```

to be sure you update the user's profile data from the form

Comment: As @itzmeontv says, also replace